# Problems with Apache Tomcat and Wamp

Tags: apache, tomcat, wamp

this is probably a noob problem but I can't get this to work. The Apache on wamp is currently on Listen 8080 because the regular localhost wouldn't work. However when I turn on Tomcat it is also on 8080 which is conflicting with wamp. I am connecting to Tomcat via Eclipse plugin. With Tomcat on I can't get into phpmyadmin on wamp.

Apache's httpd.conf in wamp is set to:

```
Listen 8080

ServerName localhost:80
```

Only with this setting I can get wamp to work.

localhost:8080 will work and 127.0.0.1:8080 works as well. Turning on Tomcat will automatically override wamp's settings. How can I get wamp to just be a regular localhost address and not have it take an 8080 port where Tomcat is sitting on?

Comment: Since this is more of a question of server configuration, you might want to consider posting this question on serverfault instead.

Comment: But in any case, you have to have administrative privileges to bind to port 80.  Also, only one process can listen on a port at a time.

Comment: Also, this isn't a crisis, but you probably want your `ServerName` to reflect your listening port.  So, `Servername localhost:8080` or whatever port you choose to `Listen` on.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the port tomcat is using.

- Go to conf folder in tomcat installation directory

  e.g. C:\Tomcat 6.0\conf\
- Edit following tag in server.xml file

- Change the port=8080 value to port=80
- Save file.

or another solution is , you can change your wamp port from 8080 to any other one...

Comment: I have a hunch that when OP said "regular localhost won't work", he meant he doesn't have privilege to port 80.  Maybe suggest 8090 or similar instead?